# Can I get the phase/plugin:goal used in the maven command?

Tags: maven, gruntjs

We use maven for our build process and are now modifying it to use grunt to build the client side files. We have maven kick off the grunt task, but similar to maven, there are some things that we want to do only if a certain phase is run. For example, if the deploy phase is run on my maven project, I want to tell grunt to also deploy the js artifact I am creating. Otherwise, if something like compile was run in the maven project, I don't want to deploy my js artifact through grunt.

I can pass properties just fine into grunt, but I don't know how to get a property that can tell me what phase was run. Is it possible to get the phase or the plugin:goal that was run? Or even the command that was run?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have seen other Maven plugins handle this is to use different mojos, bound to the desired phases. For your example, you'd write a deploy mojo and bind it to the 'deploy' phase.

The [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) does this.  It has both Resources and TestResources mojos.  One is bound to the process-resources phase, the other to process-test-resources.  So, if I was to run `mvn compile` the Resources mojo would execute, but the TestResources mojo would not, as process-test-resources occurs after the compile phase.

[Source code for resource plugin](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-resources-plugin-2.7/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/resources/)

Comment: This is definitely a consideration, I was thinking more along the lines of having different executions of grunt plugin I'm using attached to phases, i.e. execute grunt a second time, but attached to the deploy phase and running my "publish" task.
This is a possibility, but I'd rather not have to kick of grunt more than once.

Comment: @Noremac You don't use the [Grunt Maven Plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22pl.allegro%22%20AND%20a%3A%22grunt-maven-plugin%22), do you?

Comment: Yes I do, currently, but I'm not super committed to using it. Is there something with the plugin that can help?

Comment: What you mention in your first comment is exactly what I am suggesting. I thought you were writing your own plugin.  If you are using the `grunt-maven-plugin` add the first execution bound to the desired phase, then a second execution running the publish goal & bound to the deploy phase. Maybe I'm not understanding the question, can you add a pseudo-POM snippet describing what you're after?